# psql not found: windows side postgres server through wsl

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to access windows side install of postgres through wsl. I've installed the 9.6 version at:

http://www.openscg.com/bigsql/postgresql/installers/

I have had no issues running this in windows before, or in linux, but wsl is new to me so I'd like to be able to operate on this windows version of postgres through wsl so I can use bash commands.

I've installed ubuntu from the windows store and have wsl up and running, have postgres up and running with a database, however when I try to access psql in wsl I get:

```
Command 'psql' not found ,but can be installed with:

sudo apt install postgresql-client-common
```

I don't want to install the wsl side version of postgres on ubuntu. Based on what I am seeing this is potentially a TCIP issue vs. unix socket issue. Can someone clarify so I know how to approach solving this issue?

Comment: Where is it installed and what do your PATH look like ? Have you tried `sudo apt install postgresql-client-common` ?